# Setting up Bitlocker on a VNX5300 Network Access Storage ( NAS )

Tags: network-attached-storage, emc, bitlocker

Whether it is possible to have Bitlocker ( Windows 2008 Server - Encryption  ) enabled on NAS Storage Server which is access by multiple users ?

We are using VNX 5300 NAS Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not.

Windows Server 2012 supports BitLocker for iSCSI drives directly mounted as block devices, so you may want to consider that.

You will not be able to use Bitlocker for a CIFS share.

Comment: My understanding is that, I will not be able to either Implement or Utilize the Bitlock  for a Network Shared Drive - Please correct me